# How to get value from void method?

Tags: java, void

I have a given a challenge that includes,an interface that have to implement.
But making changes at these interfaces are forbidden.

```
public interface MatrixInterface {
    
    void GetSize(Dimension dim);
}
```

and there is Dimension class that has atributes "width and height".

I want to create a matrix class and use getsize method from other classes. Is there any way getting value from void method.

Comment: Is `Dimension` mutable? Then you can simply set the values in the passed in object.

Comment: who gave you such a dumb Interface xD why somebody wants to have method with GET which can't return anything :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might set your Matrix properties based on the Dimension like

```java
class Matrix implements MatrixInterface {
    private Integer width;
    private Integer height;

    void GetSize(Dimension dim) {
        this.width = dim.width;
        this.height = dim.height;
    }
}
// Please note that this code isn't clean.
```

Or maybe the Getter is in fact a Setter.

```java
class Matrix implements MatrixInterface {
    private Dimension dimension;

    void GetSize(Dimension dim) {
        this.dimension = dim;
    }
}
// Please note that this code isn't clean.
```

Comment: Clearly neither - the method is called, after all, `get`.

Comment: @rzwitserloot I guessed a behavior from OP requirements "I want to create a matrix class and use getsize method from other classes. Is there any way getting value from void method". The objective is to "get" value from the dimension in the void method from what I understood so far...

Comment: @IQbrod Thank you all. Your solutions worked for me. I know this solutions are not clear but that was the task. I am newbie so maybe i didn't explain my problem clearly. But thanks  again for your help.

Comment: @rzwitserloot  Thank you. Your explanation was clear and deeply. That is very important for a junior.

Comment: @Asya I never forget that there's no stupid questions and that we've all started as beginners ... StackOverflow is rude with beginners as they don't really know how to describe their problems (that you rn)... But hey ! Don't give up, some will try their best to help you ;)

Answer (score 1):

This is highly unusual java. Unusual in that it is 'legal' (it compiles), but it is not idiomatic (idiomatic java = written the way the community at large tends to program and how the authors of java itself as well as almost all of the libraries available to it expect you to write. If you fail to write idiomatic java, it may compile and run but the code will be hard to read by other java programmers and you'll run into a ton of friction when using other libraries).

It is in fact so non-idiomatic, 3 people have tried to answer so far who seem to fail to get this, or they do get it and are so appalled they have convinced themselves it's something else.

I get that this is a course, so you're going to have to just roll with this, but good grief. This is horrible java code. Convention even dictates it should be `getSize`, not `GetSize`. I cannot highlight enough how bad this is. Somebody presumably paid for this course, and they want their money back, and then some. You're probably handicapping yourself more than that you're helping yourself by following this course. Abort. Eject.

The key clue is that `Dimension`, assuming that is referring to `java.awt.Dimension`, is **mutable**. You can change it. What they want you to do is:

```
public void getSize(Dimension d) {
    d.setSize(yourWidth, yourHeight);
}
```

And this can be used by a caller:

```
Dimension d = new Dimension();
matrix.getSize(d);
System.out.printf("The matrix size is [%d, %d]\n", d.width, d.height);
```